# Trying to bind a list to a gridview update changes are lost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a list ofT of class clsAnswers:

this is that class

```
<Serializable()> Public Class clsAnswer
Public Property Text As String
Public Property AnswerID As Integer
Public Property IsCorrect As Boolean
Public Sub New(Text As String, IsCorrect As Boolean, Id As Integer)
    Me.Text = Text
    Me.IsCorrect = IsCorrect
    Me.AnswerID = Id
End Sub
```

End Class

I am binding this to a Gridview.
This is working ok, I see my data in the grid.

The problem I'm having is when I click edit in the grid and enter a new value and click update the new value is apparently lost.

This is perhaps a problem with persisting the data correctly.  I don't have a good understanding of how it is supposed to work in a web page.

When the code gets to GridView1_RowUpdating the new values have been lost and the old values are empty.

I'm assuming I am doing the postback wrong here is my pageload:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then

       Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 1", False, 1))
        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 2", False, 2))
        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 3", False, 3))
        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 4", False, 4))

        ViewState("Grid") = Answers
        GridView1.DataSource = Answers
        GridView1.DataKeyNames = {"AnswerID"}
        GridView1.DataBind()
   Else
        Answers = ViewState("Grid")
        GridView1.DataSource = Answers
        GridView1.DataBind()
   End If
```

I have tried all I can think of are you able to spot what I am doing wrong?

I have modified the page load to:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 1", False, 1))
        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 2", False, 2))
        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 3", False, 3))
        Answers.Add(New clsAnswer("Answer 4", False, 4))

        ViewState("Grid") = Answers
        GridView1.DataSource = Answers
        GridView1.DataKeyNames = {"AnswerID"}
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        Answers = ViewState("Grid")
    End If

End Sub
```

I have GridView1_RowUpdating as :

```
    Private Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating

    Answers(e.RowIndex).Text = e.NewValues!Text.ToString
    Answers(e.RowIndex).IsCorrect = e.NewValues!IsCorrect
    ViewState("Grid") = Answers
    Answers = ViewState("Grid")
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    bindgrid()

End Sub
```

The gird is holding the data correctly but I am finding I have to click on 'Edit' and 'update' twice any idea why

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code

```
Else
    Answers = ViewState("Grid")
    GridView1.DataSource = Answers
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

The reason is that you rebind the orignal data to the GridView on PostBack and therefore all changes you made are overwritten with the values from `ViewState("Grid")`

Comment: I'm finding I have to click on Edit and Update twice any idea why?